# Is $\sqrt[3]{2}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Is $\sqrt[3]{2}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n$, where $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$?

I think the answer is no, but I can't give a full proof. Assume the contrary, we then have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, can I say $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/ \mathbb{Q}$ is a cyclic extension but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is not, so this is a contradiction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint 1: Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Hint 2: If $L/K$ is Galois, normal subgroups $H \subseteq \text{Gal}(L/K)$ correspond to normal extensions $L^H/K$.

Hint 3: Is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ a normal extension?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) /\mathbb{Q}$ is not normal for $x^3-2$ did not factor into linear factors in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) $, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) $. Am I right?

Comment: @yify Yes you are :D

Answer (score 3):

Not all the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ are cyclic (e.g. $n=8$ or any $n$ with two odd prime factors).

They are all abelian, though. So all their subextensions are ***_*__*_*____**

Comment: all their subextension are abelian as well, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is not even galois, so we are done?

Comment: Correct, @yify!