# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Question is to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

As i was not so sure how to proceed i did the following thing(which may possibly be not so relevant to the Question but hope it would give me some hint to proceed).
As $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, I tried Computing Splitting Field and corresponding galois Group and ended up in concluding that Galois Group is isomorphic to $S_3$. As $S_3$ is not abelian Group there could possibly no Sub field $K$ of Cyclotomic field with $Gal(\frac{K}{\mathbb{Q}})\cong S_3$.

I am helpless after this.

Please let me know am i going in a correct path??
Any suggestion/hint would be appreciated :)
Thank You

Comment: I think you essentially have the answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sir, I am not very sure about it. Please let me know if there are any gaps, even if they are minute.

Comment: This question was recently handled [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/460397/11619). You have made the essential observation. Well done! All the subfields of all the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ are fixed fields of normal subgroups (because the Galois groups are abelian). But $\mathbb{Q}(\root3\of2)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not normal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for another nice observation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already solved it. I would phrase it as follows: Normal subextensions of [abelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_extension) extensions are also abelian. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not contained in any abelian extension, since then also its normal closure $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2})$ would be contained, but this has Galois group $S_3$.