# Let $n \geq 3$ and let $p$ be prime. Show that $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is not contained in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

I think that the following statement is correct.

> Let $n \geq 3$ and let $p$ be prime. Show that $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is not contained in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My idea for a proof is that, when $n \geq 3$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{p}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $x^n-p$ has complex roots (since they are of the form $\zeta_n\cdot\sqrt[n]{p}$). Since $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is real, we have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ contains $\sqrt[n]{p}$ but not the complex roots of its minimal polynomial. This implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ is not normal.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ cannot be an intermediate extension of any cyclotomic extension, since cyclotomic extensions are abelian (all intermediate extensions are normal). This implies that $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is whether this statement is correct, and if so, if my proof is correct. Moreover, does it hold more generally for cyclotomic extensions over fields with characteristic 0? Is $p$ prime necessary, or does it work for any $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt[n]{p}$ is irrational?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, same arguemtn as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460996/mathbbq-sqrt32-is-not-in-any-cyclotomic-extension-of-mathbbq?rq=1).

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711605/11619).