# Galois group of $x^8 - 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

To find the Galois group $G$ for $x^8 - 2$, the roots of $x^8 - 2$ are $e^{2\pi ik/8}\cdot 2^{1/8}:0 \le k < 8$, so the splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/8}, i)$ and the Galois group is generated by $f: 2^{1/8} \mapsto e^{i\pi/4}\cdot 2^{1/8}, i \mapsto i$ and $g: 2^{1/8} \mapsto 2^{1/8}, i \mapsto -i$.
$gfg = f^{-1}$, so $G \cong D_8$.

But my textbook says "$G$ has order $16$ and has a (normal) cyclic subgroup of order 8; however, $G$ is not the dihedral group $D_8$."
Oops. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: doesn't the dihedral group of a regular octagon (I assume thats what you mean by $D_8$?) have a normal cyclic subgroup of order 8?

Comment: That is what I mean by $D_8$, and it does have a normal cyclic subgroup of order 8. Apparently even though $G$ shares this feature, $G \not \cong D_8$.

Comment: I don't think that $gfg=f^{-1}$. I calculated that $gfg(\sqrt[8]2)= \varepsilon^7\sqrt[8]2$ and $f^{-1}(\sqrt[8]2)=\varepsilon^3\sqrt[8]2$, where $\varepsilon= e^{\pi/4}$.

Comment: $\epsilon^4 = -1$, while $\epsilon^8 = 1$, so $f^{-1}(2^{1/8}) = \epsilon^7 * 2^{1/8}$, I think.

Comment: @Tobias But $f(\varepsilon)= -\varepsilon=\varepsilon^5$, since $\varepsilon= \frac{1}{2}(1+i)(\sqrt[8]2)^4$.

Comment: Yes and $gfg(\epsilon^5) = gf(\epsilon^3) = g(\epsilon^{15}) = \epsilon \rightarrow gfg = f^{-1}$

Comment: SMM got it right. Let's denote $\varepsilon=e^{\pi i/4}=(1+i)\sqrt2$ and number the roots of $x^8-2=0$ as $x_j=2^{1/8}\varepsilon^j, j=0,1,\ldots7$. We see that $g$ permutes the roots according to $(17)(26)(35)$ and $f$ according to $(01674523)$, so $gfg=f^3$.

Comment: Where did you get (01674523)? I just see (01234567).

Comment: Edited my notation to match with yours. Anyway, $f^2$ keeps $\varepsilon^2=i$ fixed, so you cannot accurately detect a power of $f$ from how it maps $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ohh no nevermind I get it. Thank you!!

Comment: There are a few $p$-groups with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$. The obvious three are $C_{2^n}$, $C_{2^{n-1}}\times C_2$ and $D_{{2^n}}$. Then there are the semidihedral group (which is this Galois group), the generalizes quaternion group, and then there is one more, sometimes called the modular group $\mathrm{Mod}(p^n)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/460397/11619).

Answer (score 2):

$gfg^{-1}(2^{1/8})=gf(2^{1/8})=2^{1/8}g(e^{i\pi/4})=2^{1/8}e^{7\pi/4}=f^3(2^{1/8})$so $gfg=f^3$and G isn't D^8.

Comment: This shows $gfg^{-1} \neq f^{-1}$, to show $gfg^{-1} = f^3$ you need to show that: $gfg^{-1}(i) = gf(-i) = -gf(i) = -g(i) = -(-i) = i = f^3(i)$, as well.

Comment: it isn't necessary we know <f> is normal in the G