# Maximal abelian extension v/s maximal cyclotomic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

i have a question on two infinite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Write $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$ for the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, that is

$$\mathbb{Q}^{ab} = \prod_{L/\mathbb{Q} \mbox{ abelian}}L$$

and let $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\infty})$ be the maximal cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, $\mathbb{Q}$ together with all the roots of unity.

Is it true that these two fields are the same? Namely, do we have $\mathbb{Q}^{ab} = \mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\infty})$?

My attempt:

It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\infty}) \subset \mathbb{Q}^{ab}$, as the first field can be seen as an inverse limit of cyclotomic (hence abelian) finite extensions.

My guess for the other inclusion is that we can write

$$\mathbb{Q}^{ab} = \prod_{\substack{L/\mathbb{Q} \mbox{ abelian}\\ \mbox{finite}}}L$$

so that for any $L/\mathbb{Q}$ finite abelian, we use Kronecker-Weber's theorem and embed $L$ into a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. In this way $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$ would be included in $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\infty})$. However, i am not sure if this argument is correct, and i am not even sure if these two fields are equal or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: these two fields are equal, and your proof is fine.

You should replace "an inverse limit of cyclotomic (hence abelian) finite extensions" by "a direct limit [...]". The use of Kronecker--Weber theorem is essential here.
This doesn't work directly for general number fields, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919257/generalization-of-kronecker-weber-theorem-is-an-abelian-extension-always-cyclot) (although there is the theory of complex multiplication or more generally class field theory to describe abelian extensions of some number fields).