# About primes and cyclotomic extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have the following problem

> Let $p\geq3$ a prime. Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p})$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension.

I don't know how to start the problem. Any hint or help will be appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you studied Galois theory?

Comment: Yes ! I think this problem is easy indeed, but I'm  a bit confused.

Comment: I'm not sure how big of a hint this will be, but the cyclotomic extensions are Galois and have abelian Galois group...

Comment: What's the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[p]{p}$?  Why is it irreducible?  Cyclotomic extensions are normal, so the polynomial would have to split.  Compare degrees.

Comment: Niki didn't say the p-th cyclotomic extension, so I don't see how comparing degrees would make sense.

Comment: @CJD if the polynomial splits, the extension contains all the $p^{th}$ roots of $p$, hence all the $p^{th}$ roots of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment sharding4.  Where does your argument use that p >= 3?

Comment: Niki, this was the argument I was thinking of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460397/is-sqrt32-contained-in-mathbbq-zeta-n

Comment: @CJD I'll think about it ! Actually I know that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

I'll try to find a relation, thanks !

Comment: @CJD  you do need $p \geq 3$ to conclude the cyclotomic extension contains all the $p^{th}$ roots of unity.  Since $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension and $\pm1 \in \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: @CJD you have to specify $p\geq 3$ when you compare degrees, since $\pm1 \in \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: @sharding4 Can you post your answer as a solution?  I don't believe it, but I might just be missing something.

Comment: @nikilospuntajes I recommend trying to adapt the proof that shows cube root of 2 is not in any cyclotomic extension.  I think a very similar argument will work to show that a p-th root of p is not in any cyclotomic extension (as long as p >= 3)

Comment: @CJD I guess you're right.  You are going to have to appeal to the fact that cyclotomic extensions all have abelian galois groups.  My argument only gets you that $\sqrt[p]{p}$ is not contained in the $p^{th}$ roots of $1$.

Comment: @sharding4 Thanks for the response!  I do like the observation that if a normal extension contains this element, it automatically contains all p-th roots of unity.

Comment: How does this fit in with Kronecker Weber theorem which says that any algebraic integer whose Galois group is abelian lies in some cyclotomic extension? Does that mean that the algebraic integer $\sqrt[p] {p} $ not have an abelian group? This is contrary to the fact that any binomial equation has an abelian Galois group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note for $n\geq 3,\, \Bbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ is complex and for any $n$ is normal with abelian galois group.  Suppose $\sqrt[p]{p} \in \Bbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$.  Since $\sqrt[p]{p}$ is real, it is contained in the fixed field of complex conjugation, call it $K$.  As $Gal(\Bbb{Q}[\zeta_n])$ is abelian, $K$ is galois hence must be normal.  But if $p\geq 3$, $K$ doesn't contain the roots of $x^p-p$ conjugate to $\sqrt[p]{p}$, namely $\zeta_p\sqrt[p]{p},\, \zeta_p^2\sqrt[p]{p},\dots$ since the roots are complex, so it can't be normal.  Hence $\sqrt[p]{p} \not \in \Bbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ for any $p\geq 3$

Comment: You are using that normal subgroups correspond to normal extensions ?

Comment: @user1952009 yes.  definitely.  And that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: A very nice and elegant argument!

Answer (score 3):

We use a lemma:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, $k\in \mathbb{Q}$, if $x^p-k$ has no rational root, then $x^p-k$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Assume $\sqrt[p]{k} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Since the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[p]{k}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^p-k$, the lemma says the polynomial $x^p-k$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, hence $\zeta_p \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Consider the chain of extensions:

$$
F:=\mathbb{Q}\quad \subset \quad L:=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \sqrt[p]{k}) \quad \subset \quad K:=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$$

Both extensions $K/F$ and $L/F$ are Galois, the Galois group for $K/F$ is abelian of order $\varphi(n)$, while the Galois group for $L/F$ has order $p(p-1)$, it is a group which is **not** abelian when $p\geq 3$, (more specifically, it is the general affine group over $\mathbb{F}_p$), a contradiction, hence $\sqrt[p]{k} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

Comment: Why does the lemma say that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez If an irreducible polynomial has a root in a normal extension, then it has all its roots in this normal extension. "Irreducible" is indispensable here. Since we assume $\sqrt[p]{k}$ is in this normal extension, $x^p-k$ splits completely there

Comment: Yup, I know: I was suggesting you edit that into the answer :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for suggestion :), I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) \sim \mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is an abelian (and Galois) extension. Thus for any field $F \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ is a subgroup of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ and $  F/\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extension.
- Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p},\zeta_p)$.
  $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q}]= p-1$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p}):\mathbb{Q}]= p$ so
  $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = p(p-1)$ and its Galois group $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has elements of the form $$\sigma_{a,b}(\zeta_p^l \sqrt[p]{p}) = \sigma_{a,b}(\zeta_p^l)\sigma_{a,b}( \sqrt[p]{p})=\zeta_p^{al}\zeta_p^b \sqrt[p]{p}, \qquad a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times,b \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

  and hence for $p \ge 3$ :
  $$\sigma_{2,1}( \sigma_{1,2}(\zeta_p^l \sqrt[p]{p}))=\zeta_p^{2l+4+1} \sqrt[p]{p} \ne \sigma_{1,2}(\sigma_{2,1}( \zeta_p^l \sqrt[p]{p}))=\zeta_p^{2l+3} \sqrt[p]{p}$$
  Therefore $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is not an abelian group so neither $K$ nor $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{p})$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.